# Angular2: How to go from an "ng serve" hosting to a Node.Js hosting

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I've made my first Angular2 application, while using `ng serve`for hosting. Now I've to add some backend(because I need some small server logic).

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40037985/angular-2-app-how-to-deploy-in-a-local-environment-on-node) who basically explain me how to host an angular 2 app on nodeJs. But `ng serve` was doing a lot of things, checking the changes, bundling the differents JS/CSS files, injecting angular into my template, getting my dependencies.

I cannot just "generate" angular web site and then, since I've to update the angular part to get the data from the web api and work with it.

So what should I do to switch from `ng serve` to an `nodeJS`?

**EDIT**:
Viewing the answer, I must not have been clear enough.
My angular JS is not an application that will on client ONLY, I've done some part of it(navigation, some form, ...) but now I need to host a server with web service and websocket to continue the work. It's not about deploying this to a productive server. It's about to moving to an environnement that allow me to work on the server and the client side.

Comment: Your question is really two questions in one: how to deploy the Angular app (to which vinagreti replied) AND how to deploy the backend (e.g. APIs, endpoints, etc.). It's hard to advise you on the latter without knowing more about your configuration.

Comment: So what problems have you had running your WebSocket server?

Comment: @AngularFrance : not really, I know how to deploy my backend, my only question is how to use Angular on NodeJS during a development stage(meaning not by doing build/ publish on every change). It is possible to do it with .net core, so why is it not possible with node.js?

Comment: @martin None, why?

Comment: I'm still not sure I follow. You can `ng build` your files to a directory and serve the files in this directory with a simple node.js server written with Express. If that's what you're trying to do, then there's [plenty of tutorials](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) to help. But in any case, you need to BUILD before you can SERVE from Node.js. Only the devserver is able to do the build-on-the-fly thing.

Comment: Unless I completely misinterpreted your question... and really what you want is to run your Angular app server-side. Then you need to take a look at https://universal.angular.io/

Comment: @angularfrance but Building and copying all the files is not OK for développement time. I'm currently starting the server side service  (which angular will interact with). The service and angular will be on the same Server. .Net core is able to do such thing with hôtel module replacement, so I was thinking it was possible on node too.

Answer (score 11):

I think I finally understood your question:

- Instead of using the devserver bundled with angular-cli (`ng serve`), you want to use **your own Node.js-powered server**.
- Also, you DON'T WANT TO STATICALLY BUILD your app (`ng build`). You want to serve the **live build** (which has to be generated automatically by the server).

Here's how you can do it:

**1) Watch, transpile, bundle...**

Webpack is perfect for that.

Create a *webpack config file* with the right settings for an Angular app. Here's an example from angular2-webpack-starter: [webpack.dev.js](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.dev.js).

The example is bit verbose. Just keep in mind the config file is where you tell webpack how to handle `.ts` files, what bundle(s) it should generate, etc.

**2) Serve the bundle(s) generated by webpack with a Node.js server**

I see two options, depending on how much control you want:

**2a. Use `webpack-dev-server` (not a lot of control)**

```
webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --watch src/
```

You can see that the webpack-dev-server uses the config file previously mentioned.

Again, you can see an example of the full command to run in angular2-webpack-starter's [package.json](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/package.json) file.

**2b. Create your own server (a lot of control)**

You could create a Node.js/Express server using the `webpack-dev-middleware`, to which you would feed the config file created in step #1.

The middleware is the magic link that will let you serve the files emitted from webpack over the Express server.

Example of a Node.js/Express server which uses the `webpack-dev-middleware`: [srcServer.js](https://github.com/coryhouse/javascript-development-environment/blob/master/buildScripts/srcServer.js).

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Exaaaaaaactly :) I don't know yet what is webPack, but your answer seems definitely to be going in the right direction, I will search some documentation of it.

Comment: Okay. :) webpack basically does two things: it tells the server how to handle each type of file (.ts, .css, .js...) and it can also "build" them for deployment for instance (i.e. bundle, minify, etc.). Webpack is one the underlying technology used by angular-cli.

Comment: ok, nice, is it the one that do the transpilation too? I will check that with my code monday

Comment: Exactly, that's the one.

Comment: I'm struggling a little bit to put all the pieces together. I took the whole `angular2-webpack-starter`, then I took the `srcServer.js` that you have mentinned, I adapted the path to reference the correct config file and the correct index.html. But now I'm no sure what should I do to run my "own server"(2b). I tried to do a `node srcServer.js`, but then I get some error(`SynthaxError: Unexpected token import`)

Comment: Take a look at the `package.json` file in the github project of the `srcServer.js` file. Locate the `"scripts"` key in the package.json, it contains an example of the command to execute to launch the server.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question but I am just having this same concern and I found ngserve proxy option useful. In development you can run node on another port then calls to /api get redirected through to node.js.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

package.json gets: 
`"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",`

then make a proxy.conf.json file like this
`{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Fantastic find! This should be accepted as the correct answer - run node & webpack server at two different ports and proxy api requests to the node server via this configuration

Comment: Link dead; documentation can be found here now: https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Answer (score 6):

run `ng build --prod` to build your application.

After building the application, you will find your final dist code in `dist` directory.

Now, use this code in your `server.js` file in Node.js.

```
(function() {
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/dist"));

    app.listen(80);
    console.log("port" + 80);
})();
```

Comment: then I cannot update my angular app to work with the data of my service...

Comment: make sure you have used correct reference to your URLs. like, if you have used `localhost` in your client, make sure your server is hosted in localhost. If you're deploying it to any hosted server on cloud, you need to provide its IP or domain name in your angular app.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is still relevant, but this might help others get a quick start:

1. Run your NodeJS server part e.g. like this

`nodemon server.js`

2. Open 2nd terminal (in VSCode Ctrl+Shift`) and start client part build & watch

`ng build --watch`

They will continue to work in parallel, each doing it's own job. This is not exactly the same as `ng serve`, e.g. this will not reflect your changes immediately inside the page, you still have to hit F5 (which you most probably did anyway before Angular). But this is fast, free and much easier than becoming web-pack guru. And you are still able to switch between terminals to check for any output / errors.

Comment: For the first step, an alternative command that does not require any configuration: `http-server ./dist -p <your-port> -t0`

Answer (score 2):

Angular app is a HTML 5 app. So you just need to serve it as a static file in NoeJs.

## How

### Build your app

```
ng build --prod
```

This command will create a folder named `dist`. The folder content is your HTML app.

### Serving your app

Just serve it with your NodeJs app pointing to the `index.html` file.

Comment: Yes, and then I will not be able to update my angular app to get data, add the websocket part, ... I don't want to build it on every change :(

Comment: If you want angular-cli features, use angular cli and not nodejs... nodejs is not a build tool.. so you can't expect it to build your app... heheheh. If you don't want to build an app to deploy, use another framework!

Comment: But angular cli doesn't allow me to develop the server side of my website. I added some details on my question.

Comment: I think you will have to run both servers `ng serve` and `nodejs server.js` at same time. Is it a problem for you? You don't need to stop one to run other... so you can develop both at same time... Once you are ready to deploy. Just run `ng build` and point your nodejs app to serve the dist folder as the main app.

Comment: I would like to be the closest of my final environment. And if Visual studio is able to do some hot replacement when having an angular2 on asp.net core, I was thinking it was also possible on nodeJS

Answer (score 2):

`ng serve` is only for development. It is not intended as a production web server.

`ng build --prod --aot --no-sourcemap` will bundle your application ready for production and place it in your `dist/` directory.

If you want to use Node.js you can use Express with the static file middleware. You will probably also want a RewriteRule middleware to support serverside HTML5 Pushstate.

In reality you don't need NodeJS to serve your built site as it will just be flat files. Nginx, Apache or IIS with rewrite rules to support HTML5 Pushstate will be enough.

Comment: I know that `ng serve` is not for production...  Like I also said, I cannot just build it since I've to do my rest service on the server side and get the data from the angular app and work with those data. So to do so, I need to have a production environnement that allow me to have some rest service on the server while allowing me to edit the angular app. I did choose angular for that. 

And like I said, now I've to do the "non-flat-file" part. So please, how do I switch from `ng serve` to NodeJs?

Comment: What do you mean non flat file part? What are you asking? Are you asking How to set up an api?

Comment: No no, this part I know, I'm just saying that since I don't have the api finished yet, the angular part is not finished to, so I've to have the two in parallel to finish to build the website before I can use your command and build it once for all